# How to extract head lines starting with a specific char (leading spaces neglected)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to extract the comment lines from matlab codes.

```
%% header comments
% description of function
% explanations of args
%... 

function out = myfunc(in)
...
% in-code comment
...
%%
```

I tried `grep "^%" *.m`, but it outputs all comment lines.

I want the comments in the head only

```
%% header comments
% description of function
% explanations of args
%...
```

So, it should stop before `function out = myfunc(in)`. Preceding spaces and empty lines are neglected.

How can I make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract all comments before the `function` keyword, you can use `sed` with two-level filtering:

```
sed -n '1,/^function/{/^%/p}' file
```

For all the lines (from the first) until the `function`, print only those that start with the comment character `%` (skipping non-comment and empty lines).

---

**In detail**. The first part, `n,/regex/` is a [range address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses), with the starting address in line `1`, and ending address in the first line (after `1`) that starts with `function` string.

If `function` is not guaranteed to occur, you could use `[[:alnum:]]` or `[[:alpha:]]` instead. On GNU `sed`, additional name for word characters is available, `\w`.

The second part, `{/regex/ p}` is executed only for lines previously selected (addressed). And the `p` (print) action is executed only for the lines that start with `%`.

Also note the `-n` flag: it prevents `sed` from printing each line by default. Line is printed only with an explicit `p` action.

---

Example:

```
$ cat file
%% header comments
% description of function
% explanations of args

% date: ...
% author: ...

function out = myfunc(in)
...
% in-code comment
...
%%
```

Result:

```
$ sed -n '1,/^function/{/^%/p}' file
%% header comments
% description of function
% explanations of args
% date: ...
% author: ...
```

Comment: Works. And since there is no guarantee there is always a `function` keyword, I replaced as `for f in *.m; do sed -n '1,/^\w/{/^%/p}' $f; done`. It will be appreciated if you can give simple explanations how it processes the text, e.g. `1,`.

Comment: I'll explain it, btw be aware the `\w` is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to start printing when a comment is seen and exit on the first non comment line:

```
$ awk '/^%/{f=1} /^[^%]/{exit} f' file
%% header comments
% description of function
% explanations of args
%...
```